# How do I fix java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object error

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have this sample implementation and test but I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
...
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed
...
```

```java
...

@Service
public class FirebaseService {
    ...

    public FirebaseService(...) {
        ...
    }


    public FirebaseApp initializeApp() {

        try {
            ...
            InputStream inputStream = getServiceAccountFileInputStream();
            ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    public InputStream getServiceAccountFileInputStream() throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}

...

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FirebaseServiceTest {

    ...
    @Autowired
    private FirebaseService firebaseService;
    ...

    @Test
    public void whenGetAppIsEmpty_thenReturnFirebaseAppInstanceFromInitializeApp() throws IOException {
        ...
        InputStream inputStream = mock(InputStream.class);
        ...
        FirebaseService firebaseServiceSpy = spy(firebaseService);

// Specifically at this point       
doReturn(FileInputStream.nullInputStream()).when(firebaseServiceSpy).getServiceAccountFileInputStream();
        ...
    }
}
```

I am new to testing so I appreciate the help of anyone that can help me realize what I have done wrong.
Thank you

I tried spying on the autowired dependency like this and I am expecting the method to return the null input stream...

```java
...
FirebaseService firebaseServiceSpy = spy(firebaseService);
doReturn(FileInputStream.nullInputStream()).when(firebaseServiceSpy).getServiceAccountFileInputStream();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the @SpyBean annotation on the targetted service like so

```java
    ...
    @Autowired
    @SpyBean
    private FirebaseService firebaseService
    ...

    ...
    doReturn(...).when(firebaseService).doSomething();
    ...
```